# Is it possible to change data in an open worksheet through modules, openpyxl, xlsxwriter, xlwt, or xlutils?

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I need to modify the data of the excel cells without it being closed, is this a limitation of the modules or is it possible to do this process? Python returns this error: '' PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'sample.xlsx' ''
. Can someone help me ?[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF7Fr.jpg)

Comment: Why not simply copy the data into a Pandas dataframe, manipulate the dataframe, then save it into Excel?

Comment: Do you (or the user you'er logged in as) have write permissions on that file?

Comment: If you are on Windows the answer is probably no. Excel, or the OS, keeps the file locked for writing when it is open.